How can I get a keras layer to learn an AND operation
To get keras to learn to detect corners from a binary image of a rectangle I reduced the problem down to classifying a 3x3 array of pixels. The top left corner, the pixels would need to look like this.
[ [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1], 
  [0, 1, 1] ]

This generates the full set of all the possible input shapes.
def getData():
    x = []
    y = []
    template = numpy.array([[ 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1] ])
    num = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(2**9):
        n = numpy.array( num ).reshape((3, 3))
        x.append( n )
        if numpy.all( n == template ):
            y.append(1)
        else:
            y.append(0)
        s = 0
        j = 0
        while s == 0:
            if num[j] == 0:
                num[j] = 1
                s = 1
            else:
                num[j] = 0
                j += 1
            if j == len(num):
                print(num)
                break
    return numpy.array(x), numpy.array(y)

I should be able to find a classifier from a simple single convolutional layer.
def createModel():
    inp = keras.layers.Input((3, 3, 1))
    cnn = keras.layers.Conv2D( 1, (3, 3), activation = None, use_bias=True)(inp)
    cnn = keras.layers.Conv2D( 1, (1, 1), activation = "hard_sigmoid")(cnn)
   
    return keras.models.Model(inputs = [inp], outputs=[cnn])

Using this simple model I could set the weights and get the output I desire.
dw = numpy.array([ -100, -100, -100, -100, 10, 10, -100, 10, 10]).reshape((3, 3, 1, 1))
bw = numpy.array([ -35 ])
ow = numpy.array([ 1 ]).reshape((1, 1, 1, 1))
obw = numpy.array([0])

mdl.set_weights( [dw, bw, ow, obw] )
mdl.compile( loss ="mse",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-7)
)
mdl.evaluate(x, y)

Which gives a loss of:

16/16 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1ms/step - loss: 9.3703e-04

How can I train the network to learn these weights?
The basic setup to train a network is this:
mdl = createModel()
x, y = getData()
mdl.compile( loss ="mse",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
)
mdl.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=2)

It doesn't work, it just converges to a value that produces 0 everywhere, which is reasonable considering there is 1 sample out of 512 that is non-zero.
Some other observations.

Initialize the network with the correct weights the model immediately converges to a loss of 0.0038, but it still correctly predicts.
Using a weighted loss fuction just shifts the mean value
Balancing the dataset by including more positive examples also shifts the mean value.

Here is a complete version of the program.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import keras
import numpy

def createModel():
    inp = keras.layers.Input((3, 3, 1))
    cnn = keras.layers.Conv2D( 1, (3, 3), activation = None, use_bias=True)(inp)
    cnn = keras.layers.Conv2D( 1, (1, 1), activation = "hard_sigmoid")(cnn)
       
    return keras.models.Model(inputs = [inp], outputs=[cnn])


def getData():
    x = []
    y = []

    template = numpy.array([[ 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1] ])
    
    num = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(2**9):
        n = numpy.array( num ).reshape((3, 3))
        x.append( n )
        if numpy.all( n == template ):
            y.append(1)
            print("found")
        else:
            y.append(0)
        s = 0
        j = 0
        while s == 0:
            if num[j] == 0:
                num[j] = 1
                s = 1
            else:
                num[j] = 0
                j += 1
            if j == len(num):
                print(num)
                break
    return numpy.array(x), numpy.array(y)
    

mdl = createModel()
x, y = getData()

for ws in mdl.get_weights():
    print(ws.shape)
dw = numpy.array([ -100, -100, -100, -100, 10, 10, -100, 10, 10]).reshape((3, 3, 1, 1))
bw = numpy.array([ -35 ])
ow = numpy.array([ 1 ]).reshape((1, 1, 1, 1))
obw = numpy.array([0])

mdl.set_weights( [dw, bw, ow, obw] )


mdl.compile( loss ="mse",
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-7)
)
mdl.evaluate(x, y)
mdl.fit(x, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
t0 = numpy.array([[[ 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1] ]])
t1 = numpy.array([[[ 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1] ]])

print( mdl(t0) )
print( mdl(t1) )


I don't understand how this is "not about programming". Keras is a library. I am writing code to train a neural network. I cannot figure something out about how to use the keras library writing a program to make it do what I want.

To get this network to learn I had to reshape the final layer.
def createModel():
    inp = keras.layers.Input((3, 3, 1))
    cnn = keras.layers.Conv2D( 1, (3, 3), activation = None, use_bias=True)(inp)
    op = keras.layers.Reshape((1, ))(cnn)
    op = keras.layers.Dense( 1, activation = "hard_sigmoid")(op)    return keras.models.Model(inputs = [inp], outputs=[op])

The reshape layer make some things work quite a bit better.

Can train with "binary_crossentropy" loss.
The loss from evaluate is consistent with fit.

Then training
mdl.compile( loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
)
mdl.evaluate(x, y, batch_size=512)
mdl.fit(x, y, epochs=10000, batch_size=512, verbose=2)

That will learn the correct predictions, though the corner case is still off but getting closer by the end.
By balancing the dataset (adding more corner cases) speeds up the training.
I am not accepting this answer yet, because I suspect I am making a more fundamental mistake. This problem seems very simple for how much work it takes the network to learn.
